# NASM include only references like labels but not the code

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm trying to include the references of my os in my applications without including the code because the code is already in memory. Is there a way to only include the references (like os_syscall_reboot ias at 0xda0e) with nasm?

Comment: You can use dynamic linking for this, but it may be easier to define an entrypoint for system calls that dispatches based on a function code in a certain register. Or a jump table for several entrypoints.

Answer (score 0):

`os_syscall_reboot equ 0xda0e` to define an assemble-time constant will work for some ways of using it, including `call os_syscall_reboot` in some cases.

Worked with `nasm -felf32`, linking into a static ELF executable with `ld`:

```
os_syscall_reboot equ 0xda0e
call os_syscall_reboot
```

```
+ nasm -felf32 -Worphan-labels foo.asm
+ ld -melf_i386 -o foo foo.o
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000008049000

foo:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

08049000 <__bss_start-0x1000>:
 8049000:       e8 09 4a fc f7          call   da0e <os_syscall_reboot>
```

(I'm surprised `os_syscall_reboot` made it into the executable as a symbol name `objdump -drwC -Mintel` could see.  I only defined it as an assemble-time constant with equ, not `org` + a label or anything.)

**But with with `nasm -felf64`, it assembled with that 0xda0e-5 as the rel32 offset, instead of the absolute target.**  (NASM version 2.14.02, on x86-64 Arch GNU/Linux).  i.e. it jumps to `$ + 0xda0e`, which is super weird.

```
...
  401000:       e8 0a da 00 00          call   40ea0f <__bss_start+0xca0f>
```

YASM `-felf64` assembles as expected.

```
  401000:       e8 09 ca c0 ff          call   da0e <__bss_start-0x3f45f2>
```

Comment: My problem is that it should automatically create these "label equ 0xea30" in a file. I'm helping myself with https://github.com/jakiki6/bootOS/blob/master/symbols.py but it's not that elegant.

Comment: @JakobKirsch: Oh, then `global foo` in the file that defines it, and `extern foo` in the files that use it, is the normal way to make symbols visible across files.  You can still use a linker; assemble into some object file format (e.g. `-felf32`), and only make a flat binary at the end with `ld` to combine those `.o` files with symbols.  Or else `%include` all your `.asm` files into one build for using `-fbin` directly.